# Javascript variables

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a javascript that checks the user input and validates it as a number, and this is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkThis(field)
{
    if(isNaN(field.value))
   {
       alert(field.value + ' is an illegal value. Insert a number');
   }
}
</script>
```

Now I want, when the condition is true, restore the last typed value, for example: if the user types `123`, then the condition is false, but if the user types `123a` then the condition is true and the alert is triggered. I want, after the alert, the value of the field becomes 123.

This is the code of the field:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkThis(this)" />
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You'll need to store the previous value, and you'll have to set the field's value. Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var prevValues = []
 function checkThis(field) 
 { 
   if(isNaN(field.value)) 
   { 
     alert(field.value + ' is an illegal value. Insert a number'); 
     var prevValue = prevValues[field] || ""
     field.value = prevValue
   } 
   else
   {
    prevValues[field] = field.value
   }
 } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkThis(field) {
    if(isNaN(field.value)) {
      alert(field.value + ' is an illegal value. Insert a number');
      field.value = field.lastValid || "";
    } else {
      field.lastValid = field.value;
    }
}
```

Though I would strongly dis-recommend using dialog boxes to inform the user of an input error. It is distracting, irritating and frustrating to be interrupted while you type. Better use something less intrusive like colors or a little icon that appears as the user types.